# How to automate button clicking sequence in Eclipse to Stop Tomcat, Re-Build and Deploy

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, eclipse

The following, is my work-flow:

[**Please See Reference Image Here.**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LgaUn.png)

- I write code.
- I stop the Tomcat server by pressing button **#2**.
- I re-build/compile the project by pressing button **#3.**
- I start the Tomcat server by pressing button **#1.**

I simply want to be able to do this via a **single keyboard-shortcut**. I have looked into AHK, and I have looked into Eclipse's key-mappings, but to no avail. I am even considering exotic solutions such as utilizing AHK which would do a mouse-click, wait a few seconds, and then do another mouse-click using screen-coordinates - but that would be a very brittle solution.